# excluding an item from styling "CSS"

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have created a focus state which will create an outline to distinguish the focused item , however I want to exclude the outline style when I am focused on the hamburger toggle button. I have tried using :not selector as " :focus:not(.hamburger) " but its doing nothing .

-------HTML BLOCK FOR NAVIGATION LIST-----------

```
<header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/pf1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="toggle navigation">
            <span class="hamburger"></span>
        </button>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="nav__list">
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav__link">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#services" class="nav__link">My Services</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">About me</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#work" class="nav__link">My Work</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

--------CSS FOR FOCUS STATE--------

```
:focus {
    outline: 3px solid var(--clr-accent);
    outline-offset: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `:not()` pseudo selector needs to appear earlier in the selector, since it qualifies elements, not pseudo states like `:focus`. So:

```
*:not(.hamburger):focus {
    outline: 3px solid var(--clr-accent);
    outline-offset: 3px;
}
```